# Do AVX512 mask register reduce the execution time?

Tags: performance, x86-64, simd, avx512

When doing an AVX512 operation (using intrinsics) with a mask register, does the content of the mask change anything to the computing performance (latency, throughput, occupation of ports, ...)?

For example: if I perform a `_mm512_mask_fmadd_round_ps` and my mask register has only 1 bit set, is it any different than having all bits set to 1?

Supposing I'm not using the results of the computation for anything but 1 of the lanes, should I always mask when possible or is it guaranteed (by spec or by measurements on actual CPUs, but maybe likely to change...) not to have any visible effect? Maybe with intrinsics being optimized before lowered to asm the compiler can see some form of ILP?

Comment: Thanks @phuclv for the small edit. TIL the syntax for monospace font. Cheers. Little details amount to better clarity, I appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, even for the rare instructions like `vsqrtps` where the execution units aren't full width, it does the full computation regardless of the mask, and just merges at the end. [see performance numbers on https://uops.info/](https://uops.info/table.html?search=vsqrtps%20k%20zmm&cb_lat=on&cb_tp=on&cb_uops=on&cb_ports=on&cb_SKL=on&cb_SKX=on&cb_measurements=on&cb_base=on&cb_avx512=on&cb_others=on) (and https://agner.org/optimize/ for more info on understanding uops, ports, and latency).

Although I think the merge-target even needs to be ready before the uop can dispatch, even though in theory it only needed to be ready after the ALU latency.  Zero-masking (`maskz` instead of `mask`) doesn't have this issue because the destination is write-only, not merged into.

**No, masking doesn't make anything faster, it would just cost you extra instructions to set up the mask register.**  It probably doesn't even save power (which could indirectly help performance by allowing higher turbo for longer).

CPUs already run most SIMD instructions with fixed latency for the 512, 256, and 128-bit versions, using wide execution units, so skipping some work would just mean some elements of the execution unit go idle; the whole point of short-vector CPU-style SIMD is to stuff more work into fewer instructions because finding dependencies between instructions (or uops) and out-of-order scheduling them to execution ports is complex and power-expensive to scale up.

Breaking them up and looking for idle elements of SIMD execution units to try to send other work to those parts of an execution unit would defeat the purpose, requiring scheduling of each element separately.

(GPU-style SIMD has a simple pipeline for each execution unit so it does basically work that way.  CPUs care about latency, not just throughput, so they have one wide out-of-order exec pipeline per core, not huge numbers of pipelines.)

---

If the only element you care about is known to be in the low 128 or 256 bits, you can use the `_mm_fmadd_ps` or `_mm256_fmadd_ps` version (although the rounding-override version is only available for 512-bit vector width, so if you need the `_round` override version, it has to be 512).

Clang has a pretty clever shuffle optimizer that can sometimes see through compile-time-constant shuffles and notice that only one element is later extracted, and optimize accordingly.

Comment: also possibly worth noting along the lines of things masks don't do; They don't seem to appear in any store buffer / LFB logic. For example with `movl $1, %eax; kmovd %eax, %k1; vmovdqu8 (%rsi), %ymm16{%k1}{z}; movb 31(%rsi), %cl` the byte move at the end will have a false dependency on the prior mask store. As well if the masked store was a page split (say `rsi % 4096 = 4090`) and all of the portions of the mask for the second page are 0 the memory operation will still wait on the second TLB miss but NOT update the TLB. The latter can cause some pretty funky performance numbers.

Comment: And thanks for the GPU comparison. That's probably why I thought about this question (doing both right now, brain is not compartmentalizing well).

Comment: @Noah: Yeah, you can get terrible performance for something like a conditional array update if you do it with load + cmp/blend + AVX2 maskstore (on Skylake) on a clean BSS page.  If you never have an actual soft page-fault to convert the page from being CoW mapped to a zero page, every masked store (with all-zero mask) takes a microcode assist or something?  But then doesn't actually update the dirty bit in the TLB.  So you get a big penalty every vector in that worst-case.  I was going to post an answer about this on a Q&A about conditionally updating arrays, but never got around to it.

Comment: @PeterCordes what makes you think miacrocode assist? In avoiding the TLB update? Do you see MS uops? Bit of a shame. Masked loads/stores could be super useful for removing branch heavy code like [the small case of memcpy](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S;h=9f02624375c07b26e0b98bf1c6de8a4cf39fbd44;hb=HEAD#l353) if it didn't have these drawbacks.

Comment: @Noah: It was a while since I tested it, I just remember it was at least 1 order of magnitude slower than if something had dirtied the page first.  The alternative to avoid this is to unconditionally store an ALU blend result, but that can't be done thread-safely when auto-vectorizing code that doesn't write some array elements.  (In my previous comment, I said cmp/blend then maskstore, but actually I should have said just cmp, to e.g. implement `if(a[i]>10) a[i] = 5;`).  For something like memcpy with the head/tail of small memcpy, yeah thread safety (and fault suppression) are needed.

Comment: @PeterCordes are you sure it ever got into the TLB? IIRC when I tested if I added a prefetch or anything really to bring the split page in it was no issue. But with evex mask instructions no the NT maskload/maskstore instructions.

Comment: @Noah: I wasn't using *NT* mask load/store (legacy-SSE MASKMOVDQU), just the AVX2 `vpmaskmovd` that on SKL behaves mostly like AVX-512 masked operations do on SKX (perhaps the extra uop does vec->ktmp).  And no, I'm not sure about any of the reasons for the bad performance, I haven't re-tested.  This was on a page where I'd already executed a `vmodqu`, since I was (not) modifying a BSS array in place, so TLB was hot but clean.  (Without writing it first, so the hardware page table still had it mapped read-only, so fault suppression was definitely needed).   I doubt even `prefetchw` would help.

Comment: @PeterCordes You are correct and I did not recall correctly. Stores will continue to perform poorly even with a prefetch. In fact they seem to put the system in a messed up state. Masked loads alone in a loop will end up performing fine. I'm not certain if they end up updating the TLB or if the TLB miss is thrown out early. Masked loads on a page cross (with mask excluding one page) perform as well as non-masked variant. But all 0 mask on a fresh page not in TLB will perform slower and not update TLB. Stores do stay slow and **I was wrong, a prefetch will not help**, it seems you are right \

Comment: about it staying in read-only-mode or something along those lines. My intuition is that neither updates the TLB and that possibly loads are able to bail out of the second TLB miss early. Think loads are able to bail out early because mask of all 0s behaves categorically worse than mask that include some loads from one of the pages. If was updating TLB all 0 mask would be fine. And if TLB was not the bottleneck then again all 0 would be fine so think must be early bailout.

Comment: @PeterCordes Have you ever considered setting up a git repo for the `x86` tag? Would be kinda cool to have all the relevant test scripts in a common database. Imagine it would be a super useful resource.

Comment: @Noah: I haven't until you mentioned it. But IDK if a single git repo would be the way to go, seems like it could easily get too crowded / messy and hard to find anything if multiple people testing different aspects of things are pushing changes.  BeeOnRope's uarch-bench has a bunch of interesting tests.